# Unresolved reference for creation of HashMap Kotlin with mutableSetOf

Tags: java, kotlin

I am attempting to initialize a hashmap that takes in a String as its first parameter, and a set of Strings for the second parameter. Below is my attempt at creating this hashmap, but I am getting an unresolved reference to mutableSetOf are there any suggestions?

```
var map: HashMap<String, mutableSetOf<String>> = HashMap<String,mutableSetOf<String>>()
```

Answer (score 2):

`mutableSetOf` is a factory method that constructs a new mutable set. But you try to use it in the type signature of your `map` variable.

What you actually want is probably just

```
var map: HashMap<String, MutableSet<String>> = hashMapOf()
```

See https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/mutable-set-of.html

Comment: Also, it's worth checking whether you specifically need a `HashMap`, or whether any `MutableMap` will do.  If the latter, then far better to use that in the variable's type — [program to the interface rather than to the implementation](/questions/2697783).  You can then initialise it with `mutableMapOf()`, which would benefit from any improvements the standard library adds.